# SQL Self Join with null values

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having all employees(manager and employees) under one table called Employee. Table looks as follows,

### **Table**

```
+-------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
|emp_id | name       | dept_id | salary  | manager_id |
+=======+============+=========+=========+============+
|  1    | Sally      |   1     | 20000   |  null      |
|  2    | Ajit       |   2     | 20000   |   1        |
|  3    | Rahul      |   1     | 20000   |   1        |
|  4    | uday       |   1     | 20000   |   null     |
|  5    | john       |   1     | 20000   |   null     |
|  6    | netaji     |   2     | 20000   |    2       |
|  7    | prakriti   |   3     | 1111    |    3       |
|  8    | sachin     |   3     | 1111    |    3       |
|  9    | santosh    |   1     | 1111    |    2       |
|  10   | Ravi       |   1     | 1111    |    2       |
+-------+------------+---------+---------+------------+
```

Both managers and employees belong to same table. manager_id refers = emp_id who is manager.

I want to write query to count number of employees belonging to each manager. So even if certain manager doesn't have any employee under her or him the count will show as 0

Result should be as follows,

### **Expected Output**

```
+------+----------+
|Count |  Manager |
+======+==========+
| 2    |  Sally   |
| 3    |  Ajit    |
| 2    |  Rahul   |
| 0    |  Uday    |
| 0    |  John    |
+------+----------+
```

Comment: How do you know who is a manager and who isn't? *How* that output is derived from the input is unclear to me.

Comment: Employee whose emp_id is in manager_id column is manager.

Comment: How do you know that John is a manager, since nobody works for him?

Comment: Because he has null in its manager_id field, and every employee other than manager comes under one manager.

Comment: why `Uday` and `John` are also managers?

Comment: Because they have null in their manager_id field. The reson behind Ajit, Rahul are managers because their emp_id is in somebody else's manager_id field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to do left self-join on the table. The left join will ensure that there is a row for every manager even if there are no employees under them. You need to use the `COUNT()` aggregate on a field from the employee side of the join that will be `NULL` if the manager has no employees. `COUNT()` doesn't actually count NULLs so this should give you zeroes where you want them.

The `WHERE` clause in this query defines managers by looking if their `manager_id` is NULL or if there are any matches in the joined table which means there are people that have them set as their manager.

```
SELECT mgr.name, COUNT(emp.emp_id) AS employee_count
FROM Employee AS mgr
LEFT JOIN Employee AS emp ON emp.manager_id=mgr.emp_id
WHERE mgr.manager_id IS NULL OR emp.emp_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY mgr.name
```

Answer (score 2):

The correct solution likely involves *fixing* the scheme as any approach will *fail* for a "sub-manager" (who is managed and thus has a manager_id) but does not currently manage anybody.

Anyway, if the above limitation is acceptable, then people are managers *if* either

- They have a NULL manager_id (as stated in a comment), *or*
- They currently manage people other employees

Then this query (example [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fa006b/24)) can be used:

```
SELECT m.name as Manager, COUNT(e.id) as `Count`
FROM employee m
LEFT JOIN employee e
ON m.id = e.manager_id
GROUP BY m.id, m.name, m.manager_id
HAVING `Count` > 0 OR m.manager_id IS NULL
```

Notes/explanation:

- The LEFT [OUTER] join is important here; otherwise managers who did not manage anybody would not be found. The filtering is then applied via the HAVING clause on the grouped result.
- The COUNT is applied to a *particular* column, instead of `*`; when done so, NULL values in that column are *not counted*. In this case that means that employees (m) without a match (e) are not automatically selected by the COUNT condition in the HAVING. (The LEFT JOIN leaves in the left-side records, even when there is no join-match - all the right-side columns are NULL in this case.)
- The GROUP BY contains all the grouping fields, even if they appear redundant. This allows the `manager_id` field to be used in the HAVING, for instance. (The group on ID was done in case two managers ever have the same name, or it is to be selected in the output clause.)

Answer (score 1):

here is the solution; you are to make self join on employee table.

```
  SELECT e1.manager_id, e2.name, COUNT (1) AS COUNT
    FROM Employee e1 JOIN Employee e2 ON e1.manager_id = e2.id
GROUP BY e1.manager_id, e2.name
UNION ALL
SELECT e3.id, e3.name, 0 AS COUNT
  FROM Employee e3
 WHERE     manager_id IS NULL
       AND e3.id NOT IN (  SELECT e1.manager_id
                             FROM    Employee e1
                                  JOIN
                                     Employee e2
                                  ON e1.manager_id = e2.id
                         GROUP BY e1.manager_id, e2.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that helps:

```
select t1.name, count(*) -- all managers with emps
  from t t1
  join t t2
    on t1.emp_id = t2.manager_id 
 group 
    by t1.name
 union
   all
select t1.name, 0  -- all managers without emps
  from t t1
  left
  join t t2
    on t1.emp_id = t2.manager_id
 where t1.manager_id is null 
   and t2.emp_id is null
```

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
select (select count(*) from employees b where b.manager_id = a.emp_id)) as Count, a.Name as manager from  employees a where a.emp_id in (select distict c.manager_id from employees c)
```

Comment: This is wrong as it returns 0 for employees who are not managers

Comment: Correct, you want to filter out employee who is not manager? if yes then what is logic to detect employee is manager or not because you have mentioned that there may have manager who has under no employee

Comment: I have taken this logic:Employee whose emp_id is in manager_id column is manager

Comment: I have Updated my answer , now test it

Answer (score -1):

### **Query**

```
CREATE TABLE employee(emp_id varchar(5) NOT NULL,  
emp_name varchar(20) NULL,  
dt_of_join date NULL,  
emp_supv varchar(5) NULL,  
CONSTRAINT emp_id PRIMARY KEY(emp_id) ,  
CONSTRAINT emp_supv FOREIGN KEY(emp_supv)   
REFERENCESemployee(emp_id));
```

Comment: I need SQL query to fetch record not to create table

Answer (score -1):

you need to do 
`LEFT OUTER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT movies.title,sequelies.title AS sequel_title
FROM movies
LEFT OUTER JOIN movies sequelies
    ON movies.sequel_id = sequelies.id ;
```

Comment: What exactly does your answer contribute to this wuestion ehat has not been written years ago?